# NewRelic says "No data reporting for this application"

Tags: timeout, monitoring, newrelic, user-inactivity

NewRelic monitoring occasionally shows some apps as grey with the warning message "No data reporting for this application".

On drilling down into the app I can see that data has been reported that same day, but the site has simply not been active for a period (e.g. for an hour or so).

I suspect NR is designed for high volume sites where a long period of inactivity is unexpected, however there are use-cases where sites may be accessed infrequently, such as where the site provides data for one country during business hours, out of hours no activity would be expected.

Is there any way to amend the time a site has to be inactive before becoming grayed out by NewRelic so we can have sites inactive for over 1 day go gray, rather than simply those not active for the last ~hour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The agents only sends in data when the site is active (not actively means nothing to send) so it is normal for a site to "go grey".  Once the site receives traffic again it will light up green and start to reporting information.

Since having a site turn gray doesn't affect any metrics, alerting, or reports there is no configuration setting for how long to wait before turning grey.

Comment: Makes sense, thank-you.  My question was due to management having access to the dashboard asking why our systems were offline; i.e. they were confused / didn't understand the monitors.  To prevent confusion going forwards I'll set up a "heartbeat ping" to create some simple activity / ensure the site never goes grey (when working).  Thanks again.